# Enumerating stored procedure result - The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm calling stored procedure:

```
ObjectResult<ComplexType1> result = context.ListSomething(model.SelectedDatabase);
ViewBag.WebGrid = new WebGrid(source: result, rowsPerPage: int.MaxValue, canSort: false, canPage: false);
```

however when passing ***result*** as a source to ***WebGrid*** I receive:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The result of a query cannot be
>   enumerated more than once.

I'm a bit supprised as ***ObjectResult*** implements ***IEnumerable*** (not *IQueryable*). What is the background behind that exception and why I have to call **ToList()** method:

```
var result = context.ListSomething(model.SelectedDatabase).ToList();
ViewBag.WebGrid = new WebGrid(source: result, rowsPerPage: int.MaxValue, canSort: false, canPage: false);
```

to make it work? Could you perhaps provide me with some documentation that explains it (for instance from [Programming Entity Framework, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596807252.do), as I'm reading it now, but I don't remember anything that would explain that mechanism so far).

Thanks,
Pawel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `ObjectResult<T>` internally accesses `DataReader` which allows enumerating result only once in forward only way so if you want to iterate the result again without calling `ToList` first you must execute stored procedure again and get new `ObjectResult<T>` instance.

Comment: Ah, I think I remember similar example with lazy loading set to false, when type T objects were materialized when looping... Thanks for hint.